# MongoCollection returns data sync but not async

Tags: c#, mongodb, asynchronous, mongodb-.net-driver, data-access-layer

I've been trying to convert a `sync` logic to `async` and realized that my `async await` pattern doesn't work.

I've changed this code:

```
var filter = Builders<SmartAgentProperty>.Filter.Where(smartAgent => smartAgent.UserMail==userMail);
var results = await SmartAgentsCollection.FindAsync(filter);
return results.ToList();
```

to this:

```
var filter = Builders<SmartAgentProperty>.Filter.Where(smartAgent => smartAgent.UserMail == userMail);
var results = SmartAgentsCollection.Find(smartAgent => smartAgent.UserMail == userMail).ToEnumerable();
return Task.FromResult(results);
```

the `sync` version works perfectly.

the `async` version is hanging and doesn't throw any exceptions.

as it sounds, this is an extremely wierd bug.

I thought I might be doing things wrong but seems like the same pattern works in other places in my code so I'm reaching out for help.

Comment: Looks like you copied the same code twice. And why do you need "filter" in that snippet?

Comment: whoops, corrected the snippet.
and I've added the filter cause I've had issues in the past where the filter was the issue

Comment: Can you try changing the async version to this: `return await SmartAgentsCollection.Find(filter).ToListAsync();`

Comment: Also, recall that you might need to add ConfigureAwait(false) at the end of async calls or you might get deadlocked depending on the type of application you are using. `return await SmartAgentsCollection.Find(filter).ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);`

Comment: Have tried the `ToListAsync()` with no success.

Comment: I'll give `ConfigureAwait(false)` a shot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So based on Craig's Comment, issue solved!

a. I was using it wrong (`Task.FromResult` instead of actual async implementation)

b. I was missing the `configureAwait(false)`

c. should have used `Find(filter).ToListAsync()` instead of `FindAsync(filter).ToEnumerable()`

here's the code after fixing it:

```
return await _smartAgentsCollection
      .Find(smartAgent => smartAgent.UserMail == userMail)
      .ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```